# Было 5,7 яиц или 5,7 яйца?

Tags: числительные, управление, количественно-именное-сочетание

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: было 5,7 яиц или 5,7 яйца?

Comment: А можно цитату из источника? Из статьи, рецепта, задачи? Почему яйца не в штуках, не в желтках и белках?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **было 5,7 яйца.**
Иначе — имеется пять целых яиц и семь десятых (*чего?* или *от чего?*) *одного яйца.*
Существительное в словосочетаниях с дробями ставится в **Р. п. ед. числа** (т. е. существительным управляет дробная часть):
15,7 рубля; 95,7 процента; 0,7 часа; 1,7 килограмма.

Если существительное имеет форму только множественного числа (чернила, брюки, сутки), то, естественно, употребляется Р. п. мн. числа: три десятых суток, две пятых чернил.

Некоторые вопросы-ответы можно посмотреть [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1):

*Было 5, 7 яйца - пять целых семь десятых яйца (пять целых яиц и семь десятых [одного] яйца).*

Comment: Яйца имеют стандартную размерность? Семь десятых [одного] яйца равны другим семи десятым?

Comment: @shampar Вы не путаете понятия "размер" и "размерность"?