# Согласование дробных числительных

Tags: согласование, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

В среднем на одну пару приходилось 1,75 вылетевших птенцов. Или: 1,75 вылетевших птенца?

Answer (score 3):

Разницы нет — считаем мы **яйца** (см. Ваш же вопрос [Было 5,7 яиц или 5,7 яйца?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445195/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-5-7-%D1%8F%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-5-7-%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B0)) или **птенцов**, правило одно и то же: существительное в словосочетаниях с дробями ставится в Р. п. ед. числа (т. е. существительным управляет дробная часть), независимо от того одушевленное оно или нет.

Правильно: **В среднем на одну пару приходилось 1,75 вылетевшего птенца.**

*Существует в статистике и такой немного странный показатель, как коэффициент рождаемости. По нему в среднем на одну женщину в России в 2012 году приходится 1,697 ребенка.*

*Смертность молодняка в период роста в колонии значительна — на одну пару взрослых птиц приходится в среднем 1–1,5 птенца.*

**Дополнение**

[Вопрос № 287901](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C&start=0)
Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти подробное правило о согласовании дробных числительных с прилагательным и существительным (например: 0,68 сотых квадратных метров? квадратного метра?)?
Ответ. При смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Правильно: **0,68 квадратного метра.**

*При этом за последние годы на каждую женщину в Германии приходится в среднем по **1,4 родившегося ребенка**, это примерное соотношение очень низкое* (РИА Новости).

Comment: Согласен с ответом. Но я затрудняюсь объяснить такое предложение: "Яиц на каждое гнездо приходилось 5,7, а вылетевших птенцов — 1,75". Звучит вполне по-русски. В некоторых случаях может потребоваться именно такой порядок слов (в таблице или перечислении, например).

Comment: Совершенно верно, есть такое использование.  ...среднее число яиц в гнездах сапсана равнялось 3,4 [яйца], тогда как среднее число птенцов перед вылетом составляло 2,7 [птенца]. Среднее число яиц в кладке мохноногого канюка, по данным В. И. Осмоловской (1948), — 4 [яйца], а среднее число птенцов старше 10 дней составляет, как и у сапсана, 2,7 [птенца].

Comment: Спасибо! К сожалению нашёл ещё в солидных изданиях десятки цитат такого типа: "1,75 вылупившихся птенца", "23,8 золотых рубля". Такого очень много, и это в учебниках, научных журналах и книгах. Как же так?

Comment: **Определение, стоящее между числительными два, три, четыре и последующим существительным, обычно ставится в форме родительного падежа множественного числа при словах мужского и среднего рода (два больших дома, два больших окна) и в форме именительного падежа множественного числа при словах женского рода (две большие комнаты).** http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html  23 золотых рубля, но 23,8 золотого рубля; 7 вылетевших птенцов, но 7,7 вылетевшего птенца; 25 квадратных метров, но 25,3 квадратного метра.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня больше нет сомнений. И я впервые в жизни увидел такое большое количество однотипных ошибок в солидных изданиях.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что правильно будет так:

*В среднем на одну пару приходилось 1,75 вылетевших  птенца.*

Сравнить: один вылетевший птенец, два вылетевших птенца, полтора вылетевших птенца.

Определение ставится в форме мн. числа.

**Дополнение**

В общем случае управление известное:

Для числа: *одна целая (доля) и пять десятых (долей)*, то есть числитель дроби управляет Р.п. пропущенного существительного "доля": **пять долей.**

В сочетании с существительным: одна целая (доля) и **пять** десятых (**долей)** яблока (ед.ч. Р.п); пять целых и **две** десятых (**доли**) яблока (ед.ч. Р.п).

Таким образом, **сущ. в количественном сочетании (для дробных и смешанных чисел) стоит в ед. ч. Р.п.**, так как речь идет **о части целого.**

Другой пример: одна целая и пять десятых (долей) метра.

При наличии **определения:** одна целая и пять десятых (долей) **квадратного метра**. Здесь определение входит в единицу измерения.

**Редактирование**

Обычно дробное число относится к неодушевленным предметам. Сама идея членения предметов одушевленных в достаточной мере условна,  но всё-таки используется в статистике, но "части вылетевших птенцов" – это уже находится за пределами разумного, напрягая слух и воображение (как нечто из фильма ужасов).

Поэтому предложение лучше переформулировать, например:

*По числу вылетевших птенцов в среднем на одну пару приходилось 1,75  птенца*

Comment: Совершенно верно, определение обычно ставится в форме родительного падежа множественного числа при словах мужского и среднего рода: 2 (три, четыре) вылетевших птенца — при условии, что это **целые** числа. В дробных — единственное число: 2 целых и 2 десятых вылетевшего птенца.

Comment: Если сравнивать полтора и 1,5, то как лишь для того, чтобы увидеть разницу: у полутора зеленых яблок, но у одной целой пяти десятых зеленого яблока (не будем резать бедных птенцов).

Answer (score 1):

**1,75 вылетевшего птенца.**

Существительным управляет дробная часть, а определение согласуется с существительным.

> [Вопрос № 286725](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=272944)
>   Выплатить компенсацию за 4, 67 календарных дня (дней) ? неиспользованного отпуска.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Существительным управляет дробная часть: **4,67 календарного дня** (шестьдесят семь сотых календарного дня).

Comment: *а определение согласуется с существительным* — было бы неплохо разобраться, почему в солидных (научных) изданиях примерно в половине подобных случаев определение поставлено во множественное число. Это касается не только птенцов, я посмотрел ещё "золотые рубли", "канадские доллары" — там то же.

Comment: @grizzly, определение согласуется с существительным —это правило. Если вы думаете, что у есть исключения,  то на вас падает труд разбираться и доказывать. Но в данном случае Грамота подтверждает правило.

Comment: На этот раз я не спорю, а делюсь сомнениями. Я ищу и буду искать. Но Ваш ответ я поддержал.

Comment: @grizzly Спасибо. Успехов в поиске. Я ничего не нашел. Единственный известный мне близкий по смыслу случай, когда нарушено согласование определения с существительным, — это конструкции с числительными два, три, четыре (два высоких дома, три больших окна).