# Управление с дробными числительными

Tags: управление

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли такое употребление?

```
Цена продукта выросла на 23,34 условных единиц.
```

Comment: Нет. Здесь это подробно обсуждается: [Согласование дробных числительных](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/445199/183462).

Answer (score 1):

При смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 6 7/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра. [Трудности в употреблении числительных](https://studfiles.net/preview/4268617/page:38/)

***Цена продукта выросла на 23,34 условной единицы.*** (...на 24 целых 34 сотых условной единицы) - Ср. ***Цена продукта выросла на 23 условные единицы.***

Прилагательное согласуем с существительным.

*34 сотых единицы.* ***Единицы (какой?) условной.***